# SQLite3 Update Statement REALLY slow

Tags: ios, sqlite

I've spent hours trying to figure out why this update statement is slow. I've got an SQLite database on iOS and it currently takes about ~2 seconds for the STEP to complete for this update statement. As I've got between 10 and 100 repeats of this code to go through before moving on, it ends up taking between a minute and 12 minutes, which is not okay for my app.

Please help. :-)

```
BOOL result;



if (status == -1) {
    return -1;
}
else {

    if(updateStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "update Points set name = ?, type = ?, subtype = ?, description = ?, address = ?, latitude = ?, longitude = ?, porder = ?, phone = ?, url = ?, segmentTime = ?, segmentDistance = ?, segmentMins =?, userSelectedDirectionType =?, currentDirectionType=?, distanceType = ?, dateTime1 = ?, dateTime2 = ?, recalcDir = ? where id = ? ";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSLog(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [annotation.title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, annotation.typeID);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3, annotation.subtypeID);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 4, [annotation.description UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 5, [annotation.address UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 6, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
    sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 7, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 8, annotation.porder);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 9, [annotation.phone UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 10, [annotation.URL UTF8String], -1, SQ
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 11, [annotation.segmentArrivalTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 12, annotation.Segment);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 13, annotation.segmentMins);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 14, annotation.userSelectedDirectionType);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 15, annotation.currentDirectionType);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 16, annotation.distanceType);
    sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 17, annotation.arrivalDateAndTime.timeIntervalSince1970);
    sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 18, annotation.departureDateAndTime.timeIntervalSince1970);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 19, annotation.shouldRecalculateNextPointsDirections);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 20, annotation.pointID);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSLog(@"sqlite: Error while updating a point id = %d. '%s'", annotation.pointID, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    result = YES;
}
sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
return result;
```

Comment: How many rows are in your Points table at the moment? And can we see the CREATE TABLE statement and any indexes it has?

Comment: If you're updating a lot of rows you should use a transaction.

Comment: In general: I've been put in charge of fixing the database update slowness but unfortunately I know almost nothing of SQLite. Please keep that in mind. :-)

@MattGibson Between 1 and about 1000. Also, there is a base SQLite database file included with the app, which is then updated to include more columns in a run-once function (apparently there have been a few generations of the schema and they update the database based on what version it is.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reverting my SQLite3 library to a copy from an older backup of my app and somehow that it made faster. Also, I noticed that somewhere else in my code I was making repeated update statements without using a transaction (as @HotLicks mentioned) so fixing that also made a big difference. Still can't figure out why the original issue occured with that update statement taking a long time but I'm guessing that maybe the SQLite3 library I was using was flawed somehow.

Weird.